# Make a method that is both a class method and an instance method

Tags: python, decorator, class-method

Is there a way in Python to define a method that is both a class method and an instance method, such that both `cls` and `self` are receivers. In particular, I am looking to make a method that (1) knows which class it was called on when called on the class (`Foo.method(value)`) and (2) knows which instance it was called on when called on an instance (`foo.method()`).

For example, I would envision something working like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __str__(self): return 'Foo()'

    @classinstancemethod
    def method(cls, self):
        print(cls, self)

class Bar(Foo):
    def __str__(self): return 'Bar()'

Foo().method()     # <class '__main__.Foo'> Foo()
Bar().method()     # <class '__main__.Bar'> Bar()
Foo.method(Foo())  # <class '__main__.Foo'> Foo()
Foo.method(Bar())  # <class '__main__.Foo'> Bar()
Bar.method(Foo())  # <class '__main__.Bar'> Foo()
```

Note that I am aware that undecorated methods can be called like `Foo.foo(value)`, but this is not what I want because it doesn't get the `cls` variable. And without the `cls` variable, the method has no idea which class it was just called on. It may have been called as `Bar.method(value)`, and there would be now way to know that if `value` was an instance of `Foo`. An undecorated method is more like both a static method and an instance method, not both a class method and an instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by implementing `classinstancemethod` as a custom [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

In a nutshell, the descriptor must define a [`__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) method that will be called when it's accessed as an attribute (like `Foo.method` or `Foo().method`). This method will be passed the instance and the class as arguments and returns a *bound* method (i.e. it returns a method with the `cls` and `self` arguments baked in). When this bound method is called, it forwards the baked-in `cls` and `self` parameters to the actual method.

```
class classinstancemethod:
    def __init__(self, method, instance=None, owner=None):
        self.method = method
        self.instance = instance
        self.owner = owner

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return type(self)(self.method, instance, owner)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.instance
        if instance is None:
            if not args:
                raise TypeError('missing required parameter "self"')
            instance, args = args[0], args[1:]

        cls = self.owner
        return self.method(cls, instance, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

Results:

```
class Foo:
    def __repr__(self): return 'Foo()'

    @classinstancemethod
    def method(cls, self):
        print((cls, self))


class Bar(Foo):
    def __repr__(self): return 'Bar()'


Foo().method()     # (<class '__main__.Foo'>, 'Foo()')
Bar().method()     # (<class '__main__.Bar'>, 'Bar()')
Foo.method(Foo())  # (<class '__main__.Foo'>, 'Foo()')
Foo.method(Bar())  # (<class '__main__.Foo'>, 'Bar()')
Bar.method(Foo())  # (<class '__main__.Bar'>, 'Foo()')
```

Comment: Perfect. I suspected that `__get__` was somehow the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a decorator for this. This is how methods already work; the instance is passed as first argument – implicitly when method is called from instance and explicitly from the class – with the instance available, you can retrieve the class by calling `type` on the instance:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __repr__(self): return 'Foo()'

    def method(self):
        print((type(self), self)) 

class Bar(Foo):
    def __repr__(self): return 'Bar()'
```

On another note, in the `__str__` (or `__repr__`) special methods, you should return a string, not print.

I have used `__repr__` since `__str__` is not called for printing the instance when inside a container object (tuple here).

**Update**:

Considering the issues with class/instance printing in the above approach, you can use a descriptor instead to properly manage correct class and instance selection within the method:

```
class classinstancemethod():

  def __get__(self, obj, cls):
     def method(inst=None):
        print(cls, inst if inst else obj)
     return method

class Foo(object):
    method = classinstancemethod()

    def __str__(self): return 'Foo()'


class Bar(Foo):
    def __str__(self): return 'Bar()'
```

Comment: No, that's wrong. `Foo.method(Bar())` should output `(<class '__main__.Foo'>, 'Bar()')`, but yours outputs `(<class '__main__.Bar'>, 'Bar()')`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks for noting. They can use the hidden `__class__` variable in Python3 instead of `type(self)`.

Comment: That doesn't work as expected either. If you use `__class__` then it'll always return `Foo` as the class.

Comment: I anticipated this solution in my final paragraph. It is not what I am looking for because when it is called like `Bar.method(Foo())`, then `method` has no idea that its receiver was the `Bar` class. That information is lost.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Was already working on the descriptor answer, in trying to address you comment, thanks for the eye.

Comment: @drhagen Be careful with the class/instance mixing tho, as passing an instance of the base class to a subclass will fail the `isinstance` check in Python 2.